# How to find a session with a specific command

Tags: oracle, session

I have an Oracle instance with some active sessions from different users. How can I find the `SID/SERIAL` of a specific session given that this session is surely running a specific `SELECT` I know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sid, serial# from v$session where sql_id = (select sql_id from v$sql where sql_text = 'your SQL text');
```